# why install sql server in linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux

Anyone please let me know, why do i need to install SQL Server in Linux, can it came more secure or only difference of OS?

Comment: You don't have to. Do what you want and what your project require.

Comment: Great question: Because Microsoft had to admit that Windows Server has lost to Linux server in the server space. And because Windows Server will be disappearing in the not too distant future, they have to save what can be saved, which means run sql-server on Linux. Also, because Azure cloud runs on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Great question!
At first, you can save some money on the OS. For instance Windows 2016 Datacenter license for 16 cores costs $6,155. 
At second, I suspect the SSOL license should cost less than for Windows, because it does not include SSIS, SSAS, SSRS.
At third, if you are on a very small scale and low budget project, you have few free choices: MySQL & PostgreSQL. Now you have a SQLExpress. In case your project grows to enterprise level it would be no problem to switch to Standard and then to Enterprise edition of SQL Server. Just by choosing right platform you can avoid conversion later.

P.S. All of that is IMHO and applicable only to SQL Server folks, not to MySQL and PostgreSQL lovers.

Comment: If somebody disagrees with my opinion, I'd really love to see the comment "Why?". Thanks.

Comment: No, the maximum number of concurrent (TCP) connections is tied to the windows server version, so part of this applies to pg and mysql, too...